# Passing static variables as arguments to a function

Tags: c, static

Is there any problem with passing a static variable to a function as a parameter? The program printed 1 0. So, are static variables also passed by value as usual?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static main;
    int x;
    x=call(main);
    printf("%d %d",x,main);
}
int call(int address)
{
    address++;
    return address;
}
```

Comment: Notice that C uses call by value for *everything*. Changing the argument in call won't to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, static variables are passed just like any other variable.

But I would expect you to have some compile errors when you name your variable with the same name as the function.

Comment: I do not like this wording. Variables are not passed any more than an expression is passed.

Comment: That was the question. Whether only the value of the variable is pushed onto the stack and the function gets a copy doesn't seem that helpful here.

Comment: And "static variables are passed just like any other variable" is still grossly worded without refinement or clarification.

Comment: So can you articulate your concerns in any more depth than saying you don't like my wording?

Comment: "Variables are not passed any more than an expression is passed." - and with that, I am off.

Comment: There are no errors when I give the same variable and function names. Do they share the same namespace?

Comment: Yes, but when you reference one I'm not sure how the compiler knows which one you are referencing. Perhaps the local variable "hides" the function name. At any rate, I wouldn't consider that very good form.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in variable passing with statics.

Note you need to include the type in your code: `static int main;`

And I wouldn't name a variable as `main` because that might be a reserved keyword.

Comment: `main` is not a reserved identifier and you can use it to declare variables.